# Rails serialization. Does it apply well here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two models like AttackReport and AttackReportRound. Each report can have many rounds. It describes how an attack is made. This is how i have designed what i wanted to do at first. However, if an attack has, say 30 rounds, the AttackReportRound table can quickly become way too big.

Therefore, i was thinking of a way to store it in a single row if possible, or in the most efficient way. An attack round keeps information like attacker hit, damage, defender health and stuff like that.

I was thinking of serializing the data for every round in a single attackReport entry, maybe by using comma separated values or some sort of rails serialization.

What would you do in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database tables can hold a lot of rows before performing badly, especially if you are using indices properly.  Have you considered 'archiving' old AttackReport and AttackReportRound entries in other tables?  This is assuming that an AttackReport from a year ago isn't queried often -- completely depends on what your app is doing.

If you do go with serialization, I'd use the built-in Rails one (it serializes to yaml and requires very little coding on your part) before doing your own CSV solution.

Comment: I'm thinking that this table will grow really fast. Imagine, 1000 attacks per day is too few and it could mean something like 30.000 rounds entries. It seems to bad in the long run, though i agree that databases do well even with large amounts. I have thought of indices as well, though i'm still uncomfortable about the idea of way too many entries in a table. Maybe serializations is the way to go, though i think rails only supports serialization for full models(in my case the values are defined by me), i'll have to check on that.

Comment: Fair enough.  Maybe serialization is the best way.  I'm not sure if you can tell Rails to serialize only certain attributes of a model, but if not you could consider resorting to serializing an array of hashes (each hash representing a round).

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize to JSON and store it in a single row. Your database might get smaller but you'll lose some flexibility and probably performance.

You could also try a document oriented databases like Mongo. Might work out for you since AttackReportwill be a document and AttackReportRounds will be records or subdocuments.

Comment: i will probably have to check on JSON since i would not want to use something like Mongo. Thanx !